# Ajaxify Wordpress site with Social Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I installed the plugin "Ajaxify Wordpress Site" and I'm also using "Easy Social Share buttons".  The ajax loads the older/newer page content great, without loading the rest of the page (see it on www.squanderedink.com).  However, when it's loaded, the social button counters do not update.

Easy Social Share gave me the following code, which must be placed after the ajax is done loading:

```
jQuery('.essb_links.essb_counters').essb_get_counters();
jQuery('.essb_counters .essb_links_list').essb_update_counters();
```

I've added the following code, but now the counters "stack" (i.e. they counters are duplicated overtime the page is refreshed via the ajax)

```
//Update social
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").live("runScripts", function () {
        jQuery('.essb_links.essb_counters').essb_get_counters();
        jQuery('.essb_counters .essb_links_list').essb_update_counters();
    });
    $("body").trigger("runScripts"); // This line should also be added to the Ajax File
});
```

Thanks,
Kyle

AJAX code:

```
(function (window, undefined) {

    // Prepare our Variables
    var
        History = window.History,
        $ = window.jQuery,
        document = window.document;

    // Check to see if History.js is enabled for our Browser
    if (!History.enabled) return false;

    // Wait for Document
    $(function () {
        // Prepare Variables
        var
            // Application Specific Variables 
            rootUrl = aws_data['rootUrl'],
            contentSelector = '#' + aws_data['container_id'],
            $content = $(contentSelector),
            contentNode = $content.get(0),
            // Application Generic Variables 
            $body = $(document.body),
            scrollOptions = {
                duration: 800,
                easing: 'swing'
            };

        // Ensure Content
        if ($content.length === 0) $content = $body;

        // Internal Helper
        $.expr[':'].internal = function (obj, index, meta, stack) {
            // Prepare
            var
                $this = $(obj),
                url = $this.attr('href') || '',
                isInternalLink;

            // Check link
            isInternalLink = url.substring(0, rootUrl.length) === rootUrl || url.indexOf(':') === -1;

            // Ignore or Keep
            return isInternalLink;
        };

        // HTML Helper
        var documentHtml = function (html) {
            // Prepare
            var result = String(html).replace(/<\!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
                .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|script)([\s\>])/gi, '<div id="document-$1"$2')
                .replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|script)\>/gi, '</div>');
            // Return
            return result;
        };

        // Ajaxify Helper
        $.fn.ajaxify = function () {
            // Prepare
            var $this = $(this);

            // Ajaxify
            $this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy,[href^="#"],[href*="wp-login"],[href*="wp-admin"])').on('click', function (event) {
                // Prepare
                var
                    $this = $(this),
                    url = $this.attr('href'),
                    title = $this.attr('title') || null;

                // Continue as normal for cmd clicks etc
                if (event.which == 2 || event.metaKey) return true;

                // Ajaxify this link
                History.pushState(null, title, url);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            // Chain
            return $this;
        };

        // Ajaxify our Internal Links
        $body.ajaxify();

        // Hook into State Changes
        $(window).bind('statechange', function () {
            // Prepare Variables
            var
                State = History.getState(),
                url = State.url,
                relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl, '');

            // Set Loading
            $body.addClass('loading');

            // Start Fade Out
            // Animating to opacity to 0 still keeps the element's height intact
            // Which prevents that annoying pop bang issue when loading in new content

            if ('' != aws_data['transition']) {
                $content.animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 800);
            }
            if ('' != aws_data['loader']) {
                $content
                    .html('<img src="' + rootUrl + 'wp-content/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/images/' + aws_data['loader'] + '" />')
                    .css('text-align', 'center');
            }

            // Ajax Request the Traditional Page
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // Prepare
                    var
                        $data = $(documentHtml(data)),
                        $dataBody = $data.find('#document-body:first ' + contentSelector),
                        bodyClasses = $data.find('#document-body:first').attr('class'),
                        contentHtml, $scripts;

                    var $menu_list = $data.find('.' + aws_data['mcdc']);

                    //Add classes to body
                    jQuery('body').attr('class', bodyClasses);

                    // Fetch the scripts
                    $scripts = $dataBody.find('#document-script');
                    if ($scripts.length) $scripts.detach();

                    // Fetch the content
                    contentHtml = $dataBody.html() || $data.html();

                    if (!contentHtml) {
                        document.location.href = url;
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Update the content
                    $content.stop(true, true);
                    $content.html(contentHtml)
                        .ajaxify()
                        .css('text-align', '')
                        .animate({
                            opacity: 1,
                            visibility: "visible"
                        });

                    //Scroll to the top of ajax container
                    if ('' != aws_data['scrollTop']) {
                        jQuery('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: jQuery(contentSelector).offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                    }



                    //Append new menu HTML to provided classs
                    $('.' + aws_data['mcdc']).html($menu_list.html());
                    $body.ajaxify();
                    //Adding no-ajaxy class to a tags present under ids provided
                    $(aws_data['ids']).each(function () {
                        jQuery(this).addClass('no-ajaxy');
                    });

                    // Update the title
                    document.title = $data.find('#document-title:first').text();
                    try {
                        document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = document.title.replace('<', '&lt;')
                            .replace('>', '&gt;')
                            .replace(' & ', ' &amp; ');
                    } catch (Exception) {}

                    // Add the scripts
                    $scripts.each(function () {
                        var scriptText = $(this).html();

                        if ('' != scriptText) {
                            scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
                            scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
                            contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
                        } else {
                            $.getScript($(this).attr('src'));
                        }
                    });

                    // BuddyPress Support
                    if (aws_data['bp_status']) {
                        $.getScript(rootUrl + '/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/js/buddypress.js');
                    }

                    $body.removeClass('loading');

                    // Inform Google Analytics of the change
                    if (typeof window.pageTracker !== 'undefined') window.pageTracker._trackPageview(relativeUrl);

                    // Inform ReInvigorate of a state change
                    if (typeof window.reinvigorate !== 'undefined' && typeof window.reinvigorate.ajax_track !== 'undefined')
                        reinvigorate.ajax_track(url); // ^ we use the full url here as that is what reinvigorate supports
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    document.location.href = url;
                    return false;
                }

            }); // end ajax

        }); // end onStateChange

    }); // end onDomLoad

})(window); // end closure
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for '// Update the content' and put it after that code.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  Should I be able to paste the jQuery code exactly as is, or does it need to go in some function call?

Comment: I got it partially working by adding the following code, but now when the page reloads via ajax, the counters "stack" (if you reload 3 pages, there will be three counters next to each other)     //Update social

     $(document).ready(function(){
          $("body").live("runScripts", function(){
      jQuery('.essb_links.essb_counters').essb_get_counters();
      jQuery('.essb_counters .essb_links_list').essb_update_counters();    
      });
          $("body").trigger("runScripts"); // This line should also be added to the Ajax File
     });

Comment: Do you have a live link to the site, you'll have to add a $(selector).empty() right before your update code, but I can't be certain what the selector is.

MIGHT be $('.essb_links.essb_counters').empty();

Comment: The site is www.squanderedink.com

Comment: For reference, when you click "older posts" three times, the social buttons get three counters, like in this image:  http://i.imgur.com/ozqYBMd.png